# Vim's Ctrl-n shortcut doesn't work until I press ESC and enter insert mode again

Tags: vim, autocomplete, vim-plugin, neovim, youcompleteme

The vim's autocompletion keybinding `<c-n>` doesn't work properly in insert mode. When edit file and press `<c-n>`, nothing happens to me.

If I return back to normal mode by pressing `ESC` and then reenter insert mode, this shortcut works but can only autocomplete one time. Consequence `<c-n>` operations get no respond unless I repeat the `ESC`, `i` procedure.

Maybe, it is YCM that makes `<c-n>` shortcut invalid. I tried disabling YCM then everything works OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After check the manual of YCM, I got this option:

> The g:ycm_filetype_blacklist option
> This option controls for which Vim filetypes (see :h filetype) should YCM be turned off. The option value should be a Vim dictionary with keys being filetype strings (like python, cpp etc) and values being unimportant (the dictionary is used like a hash set, meaning that only the keys matter).
>
> See the g:ycm_filetype_whitelist option for more details on how this works.

Then, append the file type which you want to enable `<c-n>` shortcut to the end of the default blacklist, for example, `gitcommit` file type.

```
let g:ycm_filetype_blacklist = {
    \ 'tagbar' : 1,
    \ 'qf' : 1,
    \ 'notes' : 1,
    \ 'markdown' : 1,
    \ 'unite' : 1,
    \ 'text' : 1,
    \ 'vimwiki' : 1,
    \ 'pandoc' : 1,
    \ 'infolog' : 1,
    \ 'mail' : 1,
    \ 'gitcommit': 1
    \}
```

Now, you can active `<c-n>` and enjoy it.